# OTG USB drive showing as file instead of folder

Tags: usb-on-the-go, nexus

So I have run into a problem with my Nexus 7 2013 (2nd gen).
Some apps have not been able to find my OTG storage (such as Spotify) that is attached to my device, but it is been able to find it on my Nexus 7 2012 (1st gen) and OnePlus 3. I have narrowed down the problem to this:

[image]

In those images, you can see that the OnePlus 3 and the Nexus 7 2012(1st gen) have the OTG storage device showing up under `/Storage/usbdisk` and `/Storage/18FA-B433` folders where as the Nexus 7 2013 (2nd gen) shows up as `/Storage/0193-1CFF`. But the problem there is that the first 2 show up as folders where the Nexus 7 2013 (2nd gen) only shows up as a file in 3rd party file explorers. (I can still browse the files in the built-in file explorer in Android)

Does anyone here know what the problem could be causing it to show as a file instead of a folder and how I fix it?

The device is rooted and running 6.0.1